What book is this proof from?
I was searching for a proof for the compactness of [0, 1] and I came across the excellent image of a proof from a book. Can anyone help me identify what book this is?


Minor quibble: I'd say a problem is that it assumes $V_{\alpha}$ are open subsets of $\mathbb R$ without saying so. Yes, every open subset  $U$ of $[0,1] $ can be written as $U\cap[0,1],$ for some $U$ open in $\mathbb R,$ but that proof  skips over that. (I was particularly confused at how $(-\eta,\eta)\subseteq V_\alpha$ when  it was not even a subset of $[0,1].$

@ThomasAndrews: aren't you assuming that the topological space is $[0,1]$, where the text doesn't say so? I interpreted the theorem as saying that $[0,1]$ is compact in $\mathbb R$, which is a common context in Real Analysis.

@MartinArgerami compactness is about a topological space, not about a topological subspace. When a subspace is compact, it means the subset with the subspace topology satisfies a condition, and the open cover consists of subsets of the subspace.

@ThomasAndrews For compactness of a subspace it's perfectly valid to take "open cover" to mean open sets in the larger space (it is pretty trivial to show that it's equivalent to using the subspace topology). In intro real analysis courses it's common to define compactness that way to avoid having to talk about subspace topologies.

It's from the book Problems and Solutions For Undergraduate Real Analysis, by Kit-Wing Yu. I've discovered this by Googleing "but this certainly contradicts to the fact" (with the quotes, for an exact correspondence).

Yer a wizard, Victor

You could also Google "Therefore, we follow from the these".  Sometimes it's an advantage for an author to have inadequate proofreading!
